# Answer downvoted though it is giving the right answer

Tags: discussion, support

I had given an answer to one question which was right and fulfilling the requirement of person who 
asked the question.

Before giving an answer to that question I tried it in my sample project, and it is giving the right answer.

But still one user downvoted the answer by posting some comment. I replied to that comment that it is working fine and fulfilling the requirement of the person who asked the question. But still he did not reply to my comment and did not upvote the answer.

So is it the right way to downvote the right answer? If he does not like it, he can add the comment, because if any person is downvoting the answer then persons who have the same question may not try the answer.

Comment: Users are fundamentally free to vote however they like and are not obliged to change their vote or leave any comments/explanations.

Comment: This means we can say right is wrong and vice verse:(

Comment: In principle, yes. However, by and large that does not seem to happen. And on occasion we find out we're wrong after all and the vote is correct. But if it's not and you still get a strange downvote, shrug it off and move on.

Comment: @svrushal: No, it means that users can do what they like. Nobody is saying that the person who downvoted your answer was *right* to do so (though we can't tell one way or the other without seeing the answer), just that he or she is *allowed* to do so. I've gotten undeserved downvotes myself (and some undeserved upvotes too). It's not that important.

Comment: @ Keith Thompson: Yes I know it. But what im trying to say is if my question is right but if I receive -1,-2 or -3 then though it is right person who asked the question not go for trying it.:( and may not receive the answer if any one not given the answer for the same

Comment: He does have a point. Sometimes I've seen a 'piling on' effect, where users perusing the questions don't perhaps understand the question or the answer (whether correct or not) very deeply, just see a trend, and vote with the mob. It's happened to me going both negative and positive, even once in mass effect on the same question/answer. I just figure it's human nature and we just have to live with it.

Comment: You are right @outflak its a human nature:)) and we just have to live with it. But there should be some validation for down vote. At least any one wants to down vote any answer he or she has to give some answer to person who asked the question so that at least he will get some idea for the answer

Comment: @ Kishan Sarsecha Gajjar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098647/how-to-fetch-a-dictionary-from-an-array-based-on-a-particular-key-in-ios/23100393#23100393  I got the -1 and then some one has up voted the same. And main thing is the person who asked me the question i m still supporting him to get his requirement.

Comment: its ok dude don't worry.

Comment: On the bright side I've had an incorrect answer or 2 go +4 for the very same reason (of course on realising my error I corrected it). Usually it's stray -1s though. Not much you can do though, certainly requiring a downvoter to answer themselves isn't feasible.

Comment: I downvote sometimes when the answer is jQuery and yeah it works though the coding is garbled and should never be used when Vanilla JS is 10,000 times faster than the mess you wrote. jQuery is nice, and the only thing I believe it is good for is selectors and cross browser compatibility. Though a pro coder will know how to do this themselves. Anyways sometimes your answer may be correct but it is not the best answer that should have been written.

Answer (score 8):

I have seen and done this before myself.

There are many answers submitted that while technically they answer the question asked, they:

- do not provide a good (maintainable, reusable, best practice, etc.) way to solve the problem, even when one clearly exists, or
- do not provide meaningful information about why the asker should do what they say ('fix the problem with your block of code by using this block of code instead')

Neither is particular appropriate and is unlikely to help other people that stumble across the question.

Comment: If you did not provide a comment with meaningful information as to how the post could be improved, you are part of the problem.  Otherwise, I completely agree with you.

Comment: @Brad No. Certainly not if there is an answer not failing that point. And in general, no, being willing to assess a posts usefulness (and truthfully share that assessment, be it good or bad, by voting) does not confer any obligation to share the details of how it excelled or failed.

Answer (score 6):

IMO, it is not necessary that an answer giving the correct output deserves upvotes.

I am listing some points which can be the reason for a downvote even if the answer is producing the correct output.

- It is a code-only answer. You did not provide any explanation of logic
  behind that.
- Logic implemented in your answer may have resulted in overhead of memory
  or other resources, etc...
- Repeated answers. You provided the answer using some other words
  which already exist in the list of answers for the same question. (But
  personally don't think this deserves a downvote.)

But, if you think your answer is correct and well described then you just can ignore some downvotes. :) And continue towards your contributions to the community. That is the best way to handle it I think.

---

Attention of the OP on downvoted answers is his choice, and I think we should leave it on him. Our duty is to answer the question, solve the query if any are raised after answering and leave the rest on readers. We can not force anyone to vote or to read, even if the answer is best in the world...!!!

Comment: Yes all are saying the possibilities of rejection. I want to raise question what if any answer has -3 and though it is right:) is the questioner pay his or her attention towards the answer in that case:( So its just misguiding to that person:(

Comment: @svrushal please see the edit !! The point makes some sense in the scope of question so I edited answer.

Comment: Another possible reason - downvoting answer to a bad question (many users feel like some questions don't deserve an answer and punish anyone who posts it).